# cannot find symbol -method getvalue (); maybe you meant : intValue

Tags: java, programming-languages

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class Averager {

   private ArrayList list;

   public Averager() {
      list = new ArrayList();
   }

   public void addGrades(int test, int quiz) {
      list.add(new Integer(test));
      list.add(new Integer(test));
      list.add(new Integer(quiz));
   }

   public double getAverage() {
      int sum = 0;
      for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
         sum += ((Integer)list.get(i)).getValue();
      }
      return sum / list.size();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Integer class does not have getValue() method. There is [intValue()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#intValue%28%29) method. But for arithmetic operations you even don't have to call it - Java will do [autoboxing](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/autoboxing.html):

```
sum += (Integer)list.get(i);
```

Comment: You don't even to call intValue, java auto-unboxes ints for you. It also autoboxes them, so new Integer isn't needed.

Answer (score 1):

Class Integer doesn't have method *getValue*

Answer (score 0):

```
sum += ((Integer)list.get(i)).intValue();
```

or

```
sum += ((Integer)list.get(i));
```

or

```
sum += (Integer.parseInt((list.get(i)).toString()));
```